# Flow to Typescript

Tags: typescript, flowtype

I now have flow type code like this

```js
export interface NodeBase {
  start: number;
  end: number;
}
export type Node = NodeBase & { [key: string]: any };
```

Then I used this in the function

```js
  finishNodeAt<T: NodeType>(node: T,type: string): T {
    node.type = type;
    return node;
  }
```

There is no colon syntax in typescript and I'm not very familiar with flow.
Could you please teach me how to convert this to the corresponding typescript code?
Kind Regards！

Comment: In typescript you can do `finishNodeAt<T extends NodeType>`

Answer (score 1):

This Flow type should represent the same thing in TypeScript and it's the same syntax:

```
export interface NodeBase {
  start: number;
  end: number;
}

export type Node = NodeBase & { [key: string]: any };
```

Nothing to change here.

The one thing that needs changing is the generic:

```
  finishNodeAt<T extends NodeType>(node: T,type: string): T {
    node.type = type;
    return node;
  }
```

We use `extends` instead of a colon to specify generic constraints.

Comment: I tried this, but it will throw `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'T'`, this is so wired, `[key: string]: any ` seems to have disappeared from T

Comment: I guess flow handles index signatures differently than TypeScript? In TypeScript you can't do that because the property `type` is not definitively on type `T`.